# Why API sends me OK response and Id for new User but can't find User?

Tags: c#, api, restsharp

I'm building a API consumer in C# with Restsharp. When send I a request like this:

```cs
         var request = new RestRequest("Employees",Method.POST);
                    request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                    request.AddParameter("x-company", xCompany);
                    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    request.AddJsonBody(entity,"application/json");

         IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

I'm getting a 200 State Response and this body:

```
"{\"data\":{\"id\":\"cDhkRjdaYVNsS0lLeElONkZpZmVkUT09\",\"firstName\":\"fName\",\"lastName\":\"name\",\"email\":\"fName@mail.de\",\"companyId\":null,\"phoneNumber\":null,\"budgetGroupId\":84405,\"badgeId\":null,\"description\":\"description-dev\",\"status\":\"Unknown\",\"takeawayPayCard\":{\"reference\":null,\"cardLastDigits\":null,\"status\":\"Unknown\"}},\"success\":true,\"errors\":[]}"
```

[image]
The same request just works fine with postman.
I think the action must be succeful because the response is 200 and contains an Id for the User. But if I search for the User, it was created.
What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** Using the Postman generated Code works, but i can't replace the right-hand values in the Json because $@ is not available:

```cs
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer ###TOKEN####");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
var body = @" {
" + "\n" +
@"        ""id"": null,
" + "\n" +
@"        ""firstName"": ""test"",
" + "\n" +
@"        ""lastName"": ""test4"",
" + "\n" +
@"        ""email"": ""tesmail@mail.de"",
" + "\n" +
@"        ""companyId"": null,
" + "\n" +
@"        ""phoneNumber"": null,
" + "\n" +
@"        ""budgetGroupId"": 84405,
" + "\n" +
@"        ""badgeId"": null,
" + "\n" +
@"        ""description"": ""adessso"",
" + "\n" +
@"        ""status"": null
" + "\n" +
@" }";
request.AddParameter("application/json", body,  ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: So you send a POST request somewhere and you'll get back an entity with an ID and this seems to work. But what is the thing that doesn't work?? I guess you take that ID into another GET request and that doesn't return anything. If that's true, read the documentation of the API or ask the owner of the API or tell us, which API you're using.

Comment: @Oliver Yes I'm sending a POST request. I'm not using the Id into another GET request. I am using the Takeawaypay API, but there is no official documentation.

Comment: Maybe it's a language problem, but I really don't understand the problem. You send a POST (which normally means create something). You get back an object with an ID. What's the problem with that ID?

Comment: The Problem is, that i can't find the User created by that request. Can't find him through Postman with his Id nor through the official Webinterface. -> User doesnt exist

Comment: check if user exists in backend, if it exists there then it should be the issue with you logic which is fetching the data.

Comment: @Oliver Hab gesehen du kommst auch aus Deutschland: Ich sende den POST Request an die Lieferando API und bekomme den Status 200, sowie eine Id für den gerade angelegten User zurück. Da sollte man ja drauss schließen können, dass der User erfolgreich angelegt wurde. Suche ich den User mit der Id, kann ich ihn nicht finden. Wenn ich allerdings den Request wie im **Edit** mache, dann kriege ich das selbe Ergebnis, aber kann den User mit seiner Id finden, er wurde also wirklich angelegt.

Comment: @Brijesh its a third party API so i cant access the backend directly, just through a web interface and there is no user with that Id

Comment: And here comes the still unclear question: How do you search for that user with the given ID and what's the response?

Comment: And for your self made body: Instead create a class with the desired properties and call `JsonConvert.Serialize(myObj)` to get some valid JSON. That's much easier to handle.

Comment: I search for that User using Postman and a GET request,which works fine for other Users, and i get a 500 State

Comment: @Oliver I am now using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj)` and it works... do you know any explanaition why it works now?